# Implementation of PCA algorithm for reconstruction of data(images)

Tags: pca, implementation

I'm learning the theory and implementation of PCA algorithm in the book 'Mathematics For Machine Learning' and finishing the official tutorial notebook in `https://colab.research.google.com/github/mml-book/mml-book.github.io/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial_pca.ipynb`.

Taking an encoder-decoder perspective, as the figure [image: encoder-decoder illustration] shows, the algorithm could be formulated as a linear, lossy auto-encoder. Specifically, the centered data matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{D\times N}$, where $N, D$ are the number of samples and the sample dimension respectively. The encoder part is:
$$
Z=B^TX\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}
$$
where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{D\times M}$ is constructed by the $M$ eigenvectors as columns corresponding to the $M$ largest eigenvalues of covariance matrix $S=\frac{1}{N}XX^T$. And the reconstruction data by the decoder are:
$$
\hat{X}=BZ=BB^TX\in \mathbb{R}^{D \times N}
$$
So the projection matrix is $P=BB^T$.
But in the official implementation/solution of the tutorial in `https://colab.research.google.com/github/mml-book/mml-book.github.io/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial_pca.solution.ipynb`, it calculates the projection matrix as follows:

```
projection_matrix = (B @ np.linalg.inv(B.T @ B) @ B.T)
```

and the reconstruction matrix as:

```
reconst = (projection_matrix @ X.T)
```

And this corresponds to calculating the projection matrix as follows:
$$
P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T
$$
instead of $BB^T$.
The only difference of the implementation here is that the data matrix is transposed as opposed to the formulation in the book, so $X\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$.
So I'm confused by the way the tutorial calculates the projection matrix. Can anyone give some explanations on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since B has a **D*M** dimension then Bt *(B transposed)* will be of a **M * D** dimension, P will have a **D * D** dimension multiplied by X which has a **D * N** dimension, X¨ will have a **D * N** dimension, same as X. 
**Bt @ B** is the covariance matrix.I honestly don't know why did they insert it in the middle and change the formulas, but the formulas are valid